# PCA in 2D calculate center point in original data

Tags: center, pca, svd, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I'm trying to create a bounding box around a given dataset.

My Idea therefore was to use a PCA. I read that it won't always find optimal solutions but this doesn't matter.

What I've done so far is that I calculate the covariance-matrix and use it to calculate a SVD of this matrix.

Lets say we have a sample input like

> ```
> [40, 20], [-40, -20],[40, -20],[-40, 20],[30, 30]
> ```

The covariance matrix will become

> ```
> [1780.0, 180.0] [180.0,   580.0]
> ```

With the SVD I get the rotation matrix U:

> ```
> [0.99, 0.15]
>
> [0.15, -0.99]
> ```

and the diagonal matrix D:

> ```
> [1806.41, 0]
>
> [0, 553.58]
> ```

With my eigenvectors I'm able to calculate the slope of the lines representing the box.

I now need to get the center of the PCA in the original space not in the 0-centered space.
And I also need to find out the length of those to vectors.

Does anyone has an idea how to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
The idea was to use the two eigenvectors to calculte the maximum distance of all point to it.

The maximum distance will than be half the length of the rectangles width and height. As shown in the picture below

[image]

To position the rectangle I calculate the 4 points by

> p1.x = max1 * eigenvector1(0) + max2 * eigenvector1(1)
>
> p1.y = max1 * eigenvector2(0) + max2 * eigenvector2(1)

for all points.

Than I just had to transform the vertices and all datapoints by meanX and meanY and the rectangle enclosing the original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.Just some thoughts.

Is the centre you are referring to the mean of the data? 
Think it this way, if we can project back (0,0) to the original space, it's the mean.

To find the length, assuming you are trying to include every point in the box, you can project every point in each principle component direction and record the largest and smallest coordinates. The difference will be the length.

By the way, I am under the impression that PCA on correlation matrix is usually the more appropriate choice and I think that applies to your question too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the solution above was that using just max was not the best idea, because it will always just be minimal in one direction of the eigenvectors.
By using min and max I'm now able to create minimal enclosing boxes in both directions of the principal components.

To calculate the points I used the code below, where minDistX is the absolute value of the minimum distance:

```
p1.setX(minDist2 * U[0][0] + maxDist1 * U[0][1]);
p1.setY(minDist2 * U[1][0] + maxDist1 * U[1][1]);

p2.setX(minDist2 * U[0][0] - minDist1 * U[0][1]);
p2.setY(minDist2 * U[1][0] - minDist1 * U[1][1]);

p3.setX(-(maxDist2 * U[0][0] + minDist1 * U[0][1]));
p3.setY(-(maxDist2 * U[1][0] + minDist1 * U[1][1]));

p4.setX(-(maxDist2 * U[0][0] - maxDist1 * U[0][1]));
p4.setY(-(maxDist2 * U[1][0] - maxDist1 * U[1][1]));
```